# How would I get the positon of my avatar's head?

Tags: xna, xbox, avatar

I'm developing an XNA Game. Basically, I have a first person camera. What I want to do is get the position of an avatar's head. The reason I want to do that is because I want the camera to be on the avatar's head thus, giving it a real life view (you can see the hands and that type of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you just say "my character is X meters tall" and put the camera there.  For the player's hands you have a custom model that looks good from first person that's separate from what other people see in the world (assuming you can see other avatars).

Comment: My game is for xbox. My game gets the signed in profile's avatar and draws it. Is it the same thing from there? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with their API, but unless you can get access to the skeleton you're not going to be able get the position of that character's head.  Besides, don't want to just put the camera in the avatar's head because it's not going to look right.